# Issue with ASP.Net application on IIS8

Tags: devexpress, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am working on windows server 2012. I have added my VS2012 web application build on framework 4.5 on IIS8. Initially after adding the application when i ran it I got error "The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler." Then I added a application pool and set its framework to 4.5 and added the same in my website. Still there were errors. Then I added the Handler *.aspx, *.ashx and *.axd. Finally the application ran. Now I am using devexpress grid on the page. This is how it shows:
[image]

The images/stylying is not coming. Tried everything but nothing seems to work. Can anybody please suggest how to reolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You May try following:

- makesure css and image files exist in the server
- inspect those files loaded correctly (you may use developer tools)

  if not you need to adjust the resource path.